# Rails 4 : Jquery token Input is not saving attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-plugins

I have been working with jQuery token input and Rails 4.

## Devise gem Application controller

```
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit( :email, :first_name, :last_name,
      :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :passion_tokens => [] ) }
```

I want to save users :passion_tokens, but not able to save it. I have mentioned it in controller as per strong parameters.

## user.rb

```
attr_reader :passion_tokens

def passion_tokens= (ids)
  self.author_ids = ids.split(",")
end
```

So, please provide possible way to save the data.

Comment: Did u watch railscast for that ? 

Comment: You should use `attr_accessor` or `attr_writer`

Comment: @usmanali I have tried both but nothing seems to happen. Also, I have gone through Railcast and it's for Rails 3. I have tried this tutorial and chosen gem was working fine but jQuery Tokeninput is not saving data.

Answer (score 0):

`attr_reader` does not write to the attributes, which is the probable cause of your attributes not saving. You should use `attr_accessor` if you want to both read and write or `attr_writer` if only writing to attribute is required.